# Reduction of order method - Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with this question please.

3. Find the general solution by using reduction of order method to

$$ty'' -(t+1)y'+y = 0$$

given that $y_1(t) = e^t$ is a solution

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $y=e^tu$ and then you will get an equation of $u$.

Comment: thanks for the hint

Comment: Glad I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

$$ty'' -(t+1)y'+y = 0$$
$$(ty''-y')-(ty'-y)=0$$
$$ \left ( \dfrac  {y'}{t} \right)'- \left ( \dfrac  yt \right)'=0$$
$$ \left ( \dfrac  {y'}{t} -\dfrac  y t\right)'=0$$
$$ \left ( \dfrac  {(ye^{-t})'}{te^{-t}} \right )'=0$$
Now substitute $y=y_1v=e^tv$ and integrate.
$$ \left ( \dfrac  {v'}{te^{-t}} \right )'=0$$

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: you're welcome  @butterlord